# using unison to copy files across a LAN

Tags: lan, scp, unison

When I copy from one machine to another on my LAN, using `scp`, it opens a shell (in my case `tcsh`) and hence runs my rc file `.cshrc`.     For various reasons, I'd like to bypass all of my .rc files when I'm copying.     If I'm copying directories, I can use `unison`, which works very well. `Unison` claims also to support individual file transfers, but there's no documentation on how to do this.     Is it possible?    If not, is there a simple way to transfer files across a LAN without opening a shell?     Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I've never used `unison` directly myself.  Instead, I've used `unison-gtk` (which, I believe, runs on top of `unison`).  It does copy individual files...but it ensures the files at two locations to be the same.  Both programs run on top of `rsync`.  You can consider that, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `unison` but I've never copied individual files; only full paths. But I see no reason that when you specify which path you'd like `unison` to sync over, you can't just specify a path to a single specific file. In fact there are examples of this in the [Unison Manual](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#remote), like

```
unison a.tmp ssh://remotehostname/a.tmp
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it did indeed work.     The main reason for me to use `unison` rather than `scp` is that when I use `socket` rather than `ssh` it bypasses my startup files and is pretty instantaneous.    (I know `this is insecure, but it's a LAN to LAN transfer)